# Support Vector Machine Geometrical Intuition

Tags: math, vector, svm

[image]

Hi, 
I have a big difficult trying to understand why in the equation of the hyperplane of support vector machine there is a 1 after >=?? w.x + b >= 1 <==(why this 1??)  I know that could be something about the intersection point on y axes but I cannot relate that to the support vector and to its meaning of classification.
Can anyone please explain me why the equation has that 1(-1) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `1` is just an algebraic simplification, which comes in handy in the later optimization.

First, notice, that all three hyperplanes can be denotes as

```
w'x+b= 0
w'x+b=+A
w'x+b=-A
```

If we would fix the norm of the normal `w`,  `||w||=1`, then the above would have one solution with some arbitrary `A` depending on the data, lets call our solution `v` and `c` (values of optimal `w` and `b` respectively). But if we let `w` to have **any** norm, then we can easily see, that if we put

```
w'x+b= 0
w'x+b=+1
w'x+b=-1
```

then there is one unique `w` which satisfies these equations, and it is given by `w=v/A`, `b=c/A`, because

```
(v/A)'x+(b/A)= 0 (when v'x+b=0) // for the middle hyperplane
(v/A)'x+(b/A)=+1 (when v'x+b=+A) // for the positive hyperplane
(v/A)'x+(b/A)=-1 (when v'x+b=-A) // for the negative hyperplane
```

In other words - we **assume** that these "supporting vectors" satisfy `w'x+b=+/-1` equation for future simplification, and we can do it, because for any solution satisfing `v'x+c=+/-A` there is a solution for our equation (with different norm of `w`)

So once we have these simplifications our optimization problem simplifies to the minimization of the norm of `||w||` (maximization of the size of the margin, which now can be expressed as `` `2/||w|| ``). If we would stay with the "normal" equation with (not fixed!) `A` value, then the maximization of the margin would be in one more "dimension" - we would have to look through `w,b,A` to find the triple which maximizes it (as the "restrictions" would be in the form of `y(w'x+b)>A`). Now, we just search through `w` and `b` (and in the dual formulation - just through `alpha` but this is the whole new story).

This step is **not required**. You can build SVM without it, but this makes thing simplier - the Ockham's razor rule.

Answer (score 1):

[image: non optimal hyperplane]

This boundary is called "margin" and must be maximized then you have to minimize ||w||.
The aim of SVM is to find a hyperplane able to maximize the distances between the two groups.

However there are infinite solutions ( see figure: move the optimal hyperplane along the perpendicualr vector) and we need to fix at least the boundaries: the +1 or -1 is a common convention to avoid these infinite solutions.

Formally you have to optimize r ||w|| and we set a bounadry condition r ||w|| = 1.

Comment: ok but why there's that one in the equation? Why is +1 in the plus plane and -1 in the minus plane?

Comment: I may be stupid but I don't get how it helps avoid non optimal hyperplanes. How that one helps avoiding non opt hyperplane? Is there some geometrical meaning?